# Best design pattern to create navigation based on whether other classes/packages are available (PHP / Laravel)

Tags: php, design-patterns, laravel

We're building a new CMS for our company using Laravel.

To help with maintaining the code we have decided to make commonly used pieces of functionality into different packages. E.g. a blog package, a gallery package etc...

What I'd ideally like is for the admin area to be able to find installed packages of a certain type and build a navigation based on what they provide.

What's the best way of accomplishing this goal - is there a way of making installed packages register themselves with the admin package? I don't really want the admin package to have to go looking for other packages.

All ideas appreciated.

Comment: Closer one would be [`Chain of Responsibility`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern)

Comment: Combination of Factory and Decorator and Dependancy Injection patterns

Comment: what kind of operations do you want to support?

Comment: I guess I want a package to register itself as available for admin navigation. The admin package would then build a menu based on what is available.

Comment: How would you use a "Combination of Factory and Decorator and Dependancy Injection patterns" ?

Comment: Why don't you want your admin package to look? Reflection theoretically could do this nicely, especially if packages are implementations of an interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a registration class, make a ->registerNavigation($controller, $text) item, then in the sub-packages' service provider ::boot() functions you call the registerNavigation method
sub-packages will be registered in the order they're listed in laravel's service providers.
Of course, you could have it as complex or as simple as you'd like. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you make your packages plug-ins, you can do what you want. I don't think you need a design pattern, per se, apart from the fact that [plug-ins are usually some variant of the Strategy pattern](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/implementing-a-plug-in-architecture-in-c/184403942).

The navigation would be constructed based on the existing implementations of the plug-in interface (i.e., the existing strategies).

Reflection (if you can make it work in PHP) would get you a way to discover what things are "installed" easily. But for security it's probably better to have a more formal way to install packages (otherwise any compatible plug-in code that manages to be dropped in could theoretically get executed if you use only reflection).